# What does the layer structures and the macro structre describe in a LEF file?

Tags: pcb-design, cadence

I want to know what is the exact format of a LEF file. For example, I have the following format of LEF file ... I want to know what the layer and macro structures describe. Also, how many layer and macro could be in a LEF file?

```
LAYER layerName
  TYPE ROUTING
  DIRECTION {HORIZONTAL | VERTICAL};
  PITCH {distance | xDistance yDistance};
  WIDTH defaultwitrh
  OFFSET {distance | xDistance yDistance};
END layerName
MACRO macroName
  CLASS {PAD | CORE}
  ORIGIN point
  SIZE width by height
  SITE siteName
  PIN pinName DIRECTION {INPUT | OUTPUT };
     PORT
     LAYER layerName
     RECT point point;
     END
  END pinName
END macroName
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of files that may be useful:

- 400+ page spec: [LEF/DEF Language Reference, Cadence, v5.7, Nov 2009](http://www.ispd.cc/contests/18/lefdefref.pdf)
- A slide deck referenced by the Wikipedia article on the LEF format. [Standard Cell Library/Library Exchange Format (LEF), CMPE 641, via Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20120321172913/http://www.csee.umbc.edu/~cpatel2/links/641/slides/lect04_LEF.pdf)

I can't find the *official* source for the LEF file formats, though. The Cadence one above looks like a copy saved as part of a contest through the International Symposium on Physical Design, but probably not entirely legitimately.